# Spring-bootでサンプル通りに作ったがToStringBuilderなどでエラーが発生する

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring bootのサンプルを自分の環境で実行しようとしたらエラーで出来ない状態です。

このページの通りにコピペしました。

https://qiita.com/rubytomato@github/items/e4fda26faddbcfd84d16

**環境**

- VSCode 1.34.0
- MariaDB 10.3(x64)
- Java 1.8.0
- Spring-boot 2.0.4

---

出ているエラーは次の通りです。
**1, `Prefecture.java` にて `ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString`が認識されない**

`reflectionToString` が

> The method reflectionToString(Prefecture, ToStringStyle) is undefined for the type ToStringBuilderJava(67108964)

となってしまいます。

**2, `ActorController.java`でエラー**

`actorRepository` の `delete()` や `findOne()` が使えません。

> void org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.delete(Actor arg0)
>   The method delete(Actor) in the type CrudRepository is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)Java(67108979)
>
> The method findOne(Example) in the type QueryByExampleExecutor is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)Java(67108979)

また、

```
private Actor<Prefecture> convert(ActorForm form) {
```

で `Actor` が

> com.example.actor.repository.Actor
>   The type Actor is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments Java(16777740)

になります。

---

一応 pom.xml です

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.M3</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

application.yml(.properties みたいなもの)

```
server:
    port: 9000

spring:
    thymeleaf:
        enabled: true
        cache: false

    datasource:
        driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
        url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost/sample_db_spring
        username: ユーザー名
        password: ****

    jpa:
        hibernate:
            show-sql: true
            ddl-auto: update
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

    messages:
        basename: messages
        cache-seconds: -1
        encoding: UTF-8

endpoints:
    enabled: true
```

repository.java

```java
package com.example.demo.repository;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle;
import org.junit.platform.commons.util.ToStringBuilder;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Entity
@Table(name = "prefecture")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Prefecture {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="name", nullable=false)
    private String name;

    // @Override
    // public String toString() {
    //     return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    // }
}
```

Comment: ②の >The method delete(Actor) in the type CrudRepository is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)Java(67108979)
は「Actorを引数として受け取るdeleteメソッドは、Integerに対応していなよ」と言っています。

Comment: たぶん`deleteById`メソッドを使えば動くように思います（未確認）
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#deleteById-ID-

Comment: `findOne`も同様に`findById`かもしれないです。

Comment: >private Actor<Prefecture> convert(ActorForm form) {
という記述はサンプルコードにありませんでした。
>private Actor convert(ActorForm form) {
の間違いですか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。private Actorの部分は編集しました。delete()とfindOne()もエディタのおすすめ通りdeleteById()とfindById()に変えました。そしてfindById()に変えたことによって`Actor actor = actorRepository.findById(id);`は`Optional<Actor> actor = actorRepository.findById(id);`に変えました。残りはPrefecture.javaのreflectionToString()が呼び出せない問題を解決するだけです。

Comment: 変更したことにより、エラーは出なくなりましたか？あくまで私の予想なので、実際に動いたかかどうかの結果が知りたいです。

Comment: また、参考にしているQiitaブログの投稿者に、質問してみるのもありかもしれません。

Comment: 残りの`Prefecture.java`の`reflectionToString()`が呼び出せない問題を記載主に聞いてみたいと思います。その後runして結果を確認してみます。

Comment: Prefecture.javaのソースコードを載せて下さい

Comment: 現在はもうlombokにて実装しエラーは消えました。また、何故かサーバーが起動しなくなる問題が発生したので試行錯誤の末ユーザーdir\.m2\repository\の中身を全て消すことによって解決しました。一応コードは載せておきます。

Comment: そういえばあまり気にしていませんでしたがapplication.ymlのendpointsも何故か認識されません

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2については解決しているようなので、１について回答します。1のエラーの原因は、

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;
```

とすべき行で、

```java
import org.junit.platform.commons.util.ToStringBuilder;
```

としているからです。つまり、Apache Commons Langの[`ToStringBuilder`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html)には、`reflectionToString()`というメソッドがありますが、JUnitの[`ToStringBuilder`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.1.1/api/org/junit/platform/commons/util/ToStringBuilder.html)には、`reflectionToString()`というメソッドが無いからです。

> そういえばあまり気にしていませんでしたがapplication.ymlのendpointsも何故か認識されません

これはSpring Boot Actuatorを導入（Mavenの依存関係に追加）していないからですよね。pom.xmlに以下を追加してみて下さい。

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: 本当ですね...すみません助かりました。これで上手く行きそうです。

Comment: `endpoints.enabled` は Spring Boot Actuator のプロパティだ、というのは回答にあるとおりですが、そもそもこれは [Spring Boot 1.x 系](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-customizing-endpoints)の Actuator のプロパティだと思います。2.x系で相当するのは[`management.endpoints.enabled-by-default`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.M3/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-enabling-endpoints)でしょう。(デフォルトが `true` なので敢えて設定する必要も無さそうですが)

Comment: @yukihane 2.xではプロパティが違うんですか。ご指摘ありがとうございます。